# WEB API .NET 6.0 - current user

Tags: jwt, .net-6.0, claims-based-identity

I'm having troubles with .NET 6.0 REST Web API. I managed to do figure out just about everything, except authorizations. For my logic I need to get current user.

This is how I create Authentication, I am using JWT:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.SaveToken = true;
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
 });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();
```

this works OK.

I love this concept of app.MapGet, but for the love of god can't figure it out how to get current user.

problem:

```
app.MapGet("/Locations",[Authorize] () =>{

   //string user = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
   string user = ""; // <- how to get user -> problem :( 
   return MyMethods.GetLocations(builder, user);});
```

this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value doesnt work here..

I figure it out, how I can get a user in controller, user is in ControllerBase.
Like this:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class AppDataController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetAppData")]
    public IEnumerable<AppData> Get()
    {
        var currentUserID = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value; //<-- this is working OK
  ...
```

This is working just fine.
But the same code is not working in app.MapGet

So my question is, how do I read user  (stored in claim)?

Answer (score 0):

Just  figure it out.. :|

```
app.MapGet("/Locations",[Authorize] (ClaimsPrincipal user) =>{ return MyMethods.GetLocations(builder,   user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);});
```